# SwiftUI: Trying to update values in Firebase Realtime Database from user input, getting new reference instead of updated reference of selected stat

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I am trying to get my Firebase data to edit a stat. I can edit the data in the EditStatView, but it ends up creating a new reference stat in the database instead of editing the value of the stat I selected. I believe I am incorrectly assigning the child reference value but am not sure how to properly pull the stat key of the actual referenced data that I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct EditStatView: View {
    var stat: Stat
    var onEditComplete: () -> Void
    var viewModel: StatsViewModel
    
    @State private var editedTitle: String = ""
    @State private var editedValue: String = ""
    @State private var goalType: String
    
    init(stat: Stat, onEditComplete: @escaping () -> Void, viewModel: StatsViewModel){
        self.stat = stat
        self.onEditComplete = onEditComplete
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        
        // Intialize the state variables
            _editedTitle = State(initialValue: stat.title)
            _editedValue = State(initialValue: stat.value)
            _goalType = State(initialValue: stat.goalType)
        
        print("Initializing EditStatView with stat: \(stat)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Edit Stat Details")) {
                    TextField("Category", text: $goalType)
                    TextField("Title", text: $editedTitle)
                    TextField("Value", text: $editedValue)
                } .navigationTitle("Edit \(goalType) Stat")
                Button("Save") {
                    viewModel.editStat(statKey: stat.id.uuidString, title: editedTitle, value: editedValue, goalType: goalType)
                    //self.showing = false
                    onEditComplete()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Cancel"){ /* action */ })
         }
         .onAppear {
             print("EditStatView appeared with stat: \(stat)")
         }
     }
 }
```

Here is the editStat function:

```
func editStat(statKey: String, title: String, value: String, goalType: String) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
    
    // Reference the existing stat using the provided key
    let existingStatRef = dbRef.child(uid).child(statKey)
    let updatedStatInfo: [String: Any] = ["title": title, "value": value, "goalType": goalType]
    
    print("Updating stat at path: \(existingStatRef.url)")
    
    existingStatRef.setValue(updatedStatInfo) {(error, _) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to update stat: ", error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Update the local data model to reflect the change
            if let index = self.stats.firstIndex(where: {$0.id.uuidString == statKey }) {
                
                // Replace the old stat with the updated stat in the array
                //self.stats[index] = statToUpdate
                self.stats[index].title = title
                self.stats[index].value = value
                self.stats[index].goalType = goalType
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure there's enough info to troubleshoot. The `EditStatView` is instantiated with an existing stat (we assume). It appears the `Stat` model contain a `id` defined as a `UUID`? I suggest adding a breakpoint to your code and follow the `stat.id` var - when does it change? What is it here `let existingStatRef = dbRef.child(uid).child(statKey)`? Please do some additional troubleshooting and locate the lines of code that's failing - then update the question. Also, why this `DispatchQueue.main.async` as you're not doing anything on UI?